# What is a simple python code to practice with in arcgis?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to familiarize myself with python code. Could someone give me a simple code with an explanation of what it does so I can practice? Or a few codes with explanations if you have the time

Comment: Duplicate of [What are some resources for learning ArcPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-arcpy) and [What are the best resources for learning GIS programming with Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-gis-programming-with-python)

Comment: My mistake Ryan. This is my first time using the forum. I appreciate your response and will try avoid duplicating questions in the future

Comment: It's ok, there are lots of duplicate questions asked here, so you are not alone.  Just try to do your research by searching for logical keywords in the search bar.  For example `[python] [arcpy]` and then sort by "Votes".  Welcome to GIS.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation and tutorials about using Python with ArcGIS 10. Topics covered include scripting geoprocessing workflows, batch processing, reading and creating data, raster analysis with the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module, map automation with the ArcPy Mapping module, and creating script tools.

In addition to the main presentation pdf, each of the six exercises has a folder containing an instructions document and the data needed to complete the exercise.

http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/gallery/file//geoprocessing/details?entryID=E659B67B-1422-2418-A0FE-4F1642052299

Comment: Great! This seems much more informative than the resources I found through Google and exercises are exactly the sort of thing I needed