# Creating Isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, polyline-creation, isochrone, service-area

In QGIS I have tried to create isochrones around points for quite some time. Is there any option to create isochrones on the GUI in QGIS?

I know how to create them using pgAdmin (using e.g. @underdark's explanation and example (http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/09/creating-catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-and-qgis/)), but I would like to be able to create them using only QGIS.

There is one layer which contains the geocoded addresses around which I need to create the isochrones. It would be great to be able to create different-sized isochrones. I've tried to find a plugin or any other option to do this, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using QGIS 2.4.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not aware of any plugin currently available to do this within the QGIS GUI. Would love to be proven wrong or if someone were to create one!

Comment: I'd create a plugin if anybody knows where to find a good introduction into Python to start the programming as fast as possible, since I've got no knowledge abvout Python.

Comment: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ is on my list, though I haven't gotten around to it. Also, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/ has a number of resources listed.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Just recently, a new QGIS plugin, called [OSM Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/), has been published.
This plugin utilizes [OpenRouteService API](https://openrouteservice.org/) to compute routes and isochrones for various travel modes such as car, heavy vehicle, cycling and walking.

Nowadays *OSM Tools* is deprecated, use [ORS Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ORStools/) instead. You can check out a tutorial on [qgistutorials.com](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/service_area_analysis.html) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Maximum 120km range for iso-distances with OpenRouteService API

Comment: The "new" QGIS OSMTools plugin is deprecated resp. has been renamed with OSRTools plugin. 
The plugin comes from the openrouteservice. Firstly you need to register to get the API key. Unfortunately it is limited to 500 isochrones which is not much.

Answer (score 11):

The plugin [QNEAT3](https://root676.github.io/) offers a great tool for this creating isochrones or service areas offline based on your own network.

You can run Iso-Areas as polygons or another algorithm:

[image]

To get isochrones, choose "Fastest path" instead of "shortest":

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3 a Network analysis toolbox was added:

[image]

You can create isochrones based on your network offline by choosing the "Fastest" path type to calculate:

[image]

There are fewer settings than in QNEAT3, but no plugin is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The combination of Service Area and the Concave Hull Plugin came very close, but I noticed some inconsistencies in the way the polygons were being created.

In the end, I found out that a plugin that I use quite often actually had this functionality - and it worked great!

The plugin is the [Space Syntax Toolkit](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/esstoolkit/), just recently ported to QGIS3. When installed, it provides a tool button called "Catchment analyser" that does just that. You have to select a network and an origins layer, and then define the radii (or cost bands). Additionally, you can select length as the cost, or any of the fields in the network layer. If you want the polygons to have the same ID as the origins, you can specify it by activating the option "Origin names" and choosing the field.

[image: Catchment analyser button]

[image: Catchment analyser dialog box and options]

Not only did the polygons had the shape one would expect, but also the performance in terms of time was quite satisfactory.

In my first try some polygons were wrong, but I used the "Road Network Cleaner" tool and it seems to have fixed everything.

[image]