# Creating isochrones with given coordinates and times in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, isochrone

I have an origin coordinate and a list of destinations. Each list element has the related coordinate and the minutes spent to reach it. I want to build an Isochrone map starting from this data, without computing distances etc.

Is it possible?

This question is not a duplicate of the other one [Creating Isochrones in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/creating-isochrones-in-qgis). I do not need to only create isochrones, I need them starting from data I already have and I do not have to compute. The other question solves a routing problem, this is not the case

Comment: I think I can take it with OSM or other layers