Seeing how far you can travel by road using QGIS
I have 2 layers, one with roads of an area, and other with shops of the area. What I want to do is to produce a map which could show the roads that are 100m within the shops. Note that what I want is not just a buffer of 100m because having a shop on one side of the road within 50m of geografical distance does not mean you dont need to walk 150m of pathwalks to get there, therefore it´s not withing 100m of reach.

What you are looking for is commonly known as "isochrone", a search with this key word will provide many answer (like this one : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/creating-isochrones-in-qgis)...

Yes, thank you all !!

Use Service Area From Layer.
I want to travel 500 m from each shop point. I've snapped the points to the road layer to make sure they lie on a road then Service Area from layer.



Thank you! This is exactly what I need!

Nice! What should I do when someone answers my question?
