# Convert code VB to Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, vb

I need to convert this code to be used by python in ArcGIS

if [Field_1] < [Field_2] :
pd = [Field_1] 
else:
pd = [Field_2]

Comment: Welcome to GSE.  I removed your "ASAP" since it generally *slows* response time. In the future, please be sure to provide complete software release information and a more robust description of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [Field_1] < [Field_2]:
     pd = [Field_1]
 else:
     pd = [Field_2]
```

In this example it is pretty simple. Look over [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more examples on if statements.

If you are interested in learning more about utilizing Python in the GIS realm, please read [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/resources-for-learning-python-programming-with-generic-gis-goals-in-mind).

Comment: Depending on where you are entering this expression (i.e. Field calculator and other) you need to enclose your field names with `!` instead of `[]` for use with Python. Also, be sure to handle the case where `!Field_1! == !Field_2!`. +1 for the links!

Answer (score 7):

for a shorter code, you could use the built in "min" function to avoid the use of a code block. "min" can be used for more than one field.

```
min(!field1!,!field2!)
```