# How to programmatically execute an overpass query?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am working in QGIS using a gejson obtained from an overpass turbo query. After having defined some layer configurations and operations, I would like to update the geojson file with more up-to-date information from OpenStreetMap but without repeating the operations and configurations. I know that I could manually do the overpass turbo query again and overwrite the gejson file, but I am looking for some automated way. Maybe the easiest way is to create an script and run it, or (from what I have read -and if I am not wrong) even using QGIS' toolbox, but unfortunately I do not know where to start in both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a scripting language to automate your tasks and querying the overpass data.

Python is commonly used in GIS applications and interfaces well with QGIS. There's even an [Overpass Python library](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper). You can have a look at [these resources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3001/36886) for learning Python for GIS, you may also find some examples of scripts by [searching for the [python] & [overpass-api]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+overpass-api) tags

Comment: Thank you for your reply @raphael Could you please elaborate a little bit more on how to make script? I do not know where to start

Comment: You can have a look at the resources here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3001/36886